# error al hacer sendRedirect en metodo doFilter de una clase Filter

Tags: java, struts

Buenas a tod@s,

Tengo un filtro en mi web.xml para controlar las llamadas que se hacen al servidor de mi aplicación una vez nos hayamos logado en ésta. La clase filter que implementa los metodos doFilter, destroy e init además tiene un procedimiento limpiarSesion que lo que hace es eliminar todos los formularios y variables que puedan haber sido guardadas en sesión.

**Adjunto el código del mismo:**

```
private void limpiaSesion(HttpSession session, HttpServletRequest request) {

    /* Comprobamos si venimos de una opcion del menu */
    String cleanSession = (String) request.getParameter("cs");
    if(cleanSession!=null && cleanSession.equals("1")){

        String objectName = null;

        /* Lipiamos los formularios de la session */
        for(Enumeration enum1 = session.getAttributeNames(); enum1.hasMoreElements();) {
            objectName = (String)enum1.nextElement();

            if(objectName.endsWith("Form")){
                session.removeAttribute(objectName);
            }
        }
    }

    Object object;
    String objectName;

    for(Enumeration enum1 = session.getAttributeNames(); enum1.hasMoreElements();) {
        objectName = (String)enum1.nextElement();
        object = (Object) session.getAttribute(objectName);
    }
}
```

**En mi doFilter hago uso de este metodo si la sesion no es nula y la url a la que se intenta acceder contiene "axis2-web":**

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse resp, FilterChain chain) throws IOException {

    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) resp;
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;

    String uri = request.getRequestURI();

    HttpSession session = ((HttpServletRequest)req).getSession();
    int existe = uri.indexOf("axis2-web");
    if(session != null && (existe!=-1)){
        limpiaSesion(session,(HttpServletRequest)req);
        response.sendRedirect(ERROR+ERROR_COOKIE_EXPIRED);
    }else{
        try {

            chain.doFilter(req, resp);

        } catch (ServletException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**Cuando entra por el if y hace el sendRedirect salta el siguiente mensaje de error en la consola del servidor:**

```
  2017-11-22 12:41:09 ERROR AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter:341 - java.lang.IllegalStateException: No puedo llamar a sendRedirect() tras llevar a cabo la respuesta
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No puedo llamar a sendRedirect() tras llevar a cabo la respuesta
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.sendRedirect(ResponseFacade.java:494)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponseWrapper.sendRedirect(HttpServletResponseWrapper.java:138)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponseWrapper.sendRedirect(HttpServletResponseWrapper.java:138)
        at org.acegisecurity.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter$OnRedirectUpdateSessionResponseWrapper.sendRedirect(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:525)
        at es.aig.extranet.util.controlnavegacion.FiltroVulnerabilidad.doFilter(FiltroVulnerabilidad.java:51)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:265)
        at org.acegisecurity.ui.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:166)
        at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:275)
        at org.acegisecurity.wrapper.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:81)
        at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:275)
        at org.acegisecurity.ui.preauth.AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.java:337)
        at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:275)
        at org.acegisecurity.ui.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
        at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:275)
        at org.acegisecurity.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:249)
        at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:275)
        at org.acegisecurity.securechannel.ChannelProcessingFilter.doFilter(ChannelProcessingFilter.java:138)
        at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:275)
        at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:149)
        at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterToBeanProxy.doFilter(FilterToBeanProxy.java:98)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at es.aig.extranet.util.controlnavegacion.FiltroSeguridad.doFilter(FiltroSeguridad.java:132)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:217)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Espero puedan ayudarme, un saludo y muchas gracias de antemano!!

Comment: Seguramente un filtro anterior ya hizo alguna operación similar con la respuesta... viendo tu stacktrace veo que hay un filtro anterior llamado FiltroSeguridad, comprueba si ahí ya se ha hecho una redirección

Comment: Buenas Pablo, he seguido el flujo para ver si en algun momento hace un sendRedirect previo al de mi filtro y no he visto nada. Existe alguna forma de cancelar el sendRedirect previo?

Comment: sendRedirect, forward, sendError... hay varias formas de marcar la response como "realizada"

Comment: Acabo de ver cual es el problema, lo explico en una respuesta nueva para poder añadir un trozos de código explicativo para todo aquel que le pueda servir de ayuda.

Comment: Eso siempre es bienvenido!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema ha venido por la versión del Artifact del pom.xml que hace referencia a la librería principal donde se encuentra el método que me estaba dando problemas.

Con cada subida de código a otro entorno ya sea desarrollo, preproducción o producción... debemos de subir la versión, en mi caso la 2.8.0, pues bien en el pom de mi librería tengo el siguiente código para que me haga el despliegue "automáticamente" en servidor (Tomcat8). Digo "automaticamente" pues antes deberemos ejecutar en consola la instrucción: **mvn -P tomcat8-lib deploy ../Arquitectura**

```
<profile>
             <id>tomcat8-lib</id>

              <activation>
                <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
             </activation>

             <properties>
                <tomcat8.repository>C:\java_projects\software\apache-tomcat-8.0.28\lib</tomcat8.repository>
             </properties>

             <build>
               <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.10</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>copy</id>
                                <phase>deploy</phase>

                                <goals>
                                    <goal>copy</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <artifactItems>

                                        <!-- ARQUITECTURA LIBRARY -->

                                        <artifactItem>
                                            <groupId>es.metlife.arq</groupId>
                                            <artifactId>arquitectura</artifactId>
                                            <version>2.8.0</version>
                                            <type>jar</type>
                                            <overWrite>true</overWrite>
                                            <outputDirectory>${tomcat8.repository}</outputDirectory>
                                            <destFileName>arquitectura-2.8.0.jar</destFileName>
                                        </artifactItem>


                                    </artifactItems>
                                    <outputDirectory>${tomcat8.repository}</outputDirectory>
                                    <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                                    <overWriteSnapshots>true</overWriteSnapshots>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
               </plugins>
             </build>
       </profile>
```

Cual fue mi fallo... el IDE que uso para desarrollar es eclipse Oxygen, como bien os he comentado tuve que cambiar la versión de mi librería y para ello abrí el pom de la misma y modifiqué esta desde la pestaña Overview. Al hacer eso me cambiaba la versión y al compilar me generaba la version 2.8.0 pero no cambia la version del profile que os adjunte anteriormente para hacer el despliegue "automatico". De modo que mantenia la versión 2.7.0 y al hacer el despliegue cogía la version 2.7.0 la cual tenia un sendError() previo al sendRedirect(). Me di cuenta decompilando el código con Java Decompiler y accediendo al .class que contenía mi filtro.

Para resolver el problema simplemente accedí al pom cambie "a mano" la version del profile poniendo la 2.8.0, desplegando nuevamente y asegurandome que me había desplegado la versión adecuada.

Como bien indica Pablo en los comentarios de la primera respuesta, no puede haber un sendError previo a un sendRedirect.

Espero que la respuesta no sea muy enrevesada y sirva de ayuda. Se aceptan comentarios aclaratorios.